# restrict uploaded file which doesn't match approved mime type

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, filereader

i am trying to create a image upload mechanism which should only allow some common image files (jpg,png,gif) . If user upload any files which doesn't match those type i want to abort the process and show an error message. i wrote the following code . It has a mime type checking mechanism inside onLoadStart event handler.i am planning to check for the mime type inside loadstart and if it was ok then proceed for onload event. Otherwise abort the mission. But problem is

***whenever i upload any file ,i see an error in the console saying that fileLoadStart is not defined.Why i am getting this error?how can i solve this?***

***i can't manage to abort the mission dynamically if no match was found. How i can manage that***

[image]

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='file' id='up'>
<script>




    function readfile(e){

        if(window.File && window.FileReader &&  window.FileList){

                var file=e.target.files[0];


                var fileReader=new FileReader();

                fileReader.onloadstart=fileLoadStart;
                fileReader.onload=fileLoad;


                function fileLoadStart(e){
                        var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result).slice(0,4));

                        console.log(arr);


                        var header = "";
                        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                                header += arr[i].toString(16);

                        }

                        switch (header) {

                                case "89504e47":
                                    type = "image/png";
                                    console.log(type);
                                    break;

                                case "47494638":
                                    type = "image/gif";
                                    console.log(type);
                                    break;

                                case "ffd8ffe0":
                                case "ffd8ffe1":
                                case "ffd8ffe2":
                                    type = "image/jpeg";
                                    console.log(type);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    fileReader.abort();
                                    console.log('raeding stopped');
                                    break;


                        } 


                }

                function fileLoad(e){

                         console.log('do nothing');
                }

            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        }else{

             alert('file api not compatible with your browser');
        }  


    }
    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change',readfile,false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the way you're invoking the functions.

```
 fileReader.onloadstart=fileLoadStart;
 fileReader.onload=fileLoad;
```

Should be

either in HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='up' onloadstart="fileLoadStart(e)" onload="fileLoad(e)">
```

or in the JS:

```
document.getElementById('up').addEventListener("loadstart", fileLoadStart(e));
document.getElementById('up').addEventListener("load", fileLoad(e));
```

Comment: fileLoad and fileLoadStart need to be outside of the fileLoad function.